# Where's this islet in Saguenay Québec?

Tags: identify-this, quebec

I lighted on [this website](https://www.rivercitygranitestl.com/lac-st-jean-mapa) that contains [the picture beneath](https://www.guidesulysse.com/guides-destinations/Saguenay-Lac-Saint-Jean/349/). It cites iStockphoto.com/jnnault, but this URL is broken. User [AakashM](https://www.istockphoto.com/ie/photo/sagenay-fjord-quebec-canada-river-lake-forest-dramatic-sky-gm471692949-26144945) found https://www.istockphoto.com/ie/photo/sagenay-fjord-quebec-canada-river-lake-forest-dramatic-sky-gm471692949-26144945, but this doesn't stipulate where in Saguenay's fjords.

Please edify me if ['islet'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islet) isn't the most fitting term.

[image]

Comment: As it turns out, just googling *for* that URL eventually leads you to the relevant area at istockphoto. Here's the page: https://www.istockphoto.com/ie/photo/sagenay-fjord-quebec-canada-river-lake-forest-dramatic-sky-gm471692949-26144945

Comment: @AakashM Please see my edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Google Street View link to the same location: https://goo.gl/maps/HGrRAdph9Z2Hu7nS7. This is a place called *Le quai de [Petit-Saguenay](https://petit-saguenay.com/)*.

[image]

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal: You said it was near Saguenay, so I looked for a part of the river that was (a) fairly wide, (b) not built up, (c) had a little island near the bank, and (d) probably near a road. The rocks piled in the very foreground of your picture did not appear to be a natural formation, so an artificial embankment was likely.